# Convert String to Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have one string in List something like

```
ListofString = ['Column1,Column2,Column3,\nCol1Value1,Col2Value1,Col3Value1,\nCol1Value2,Col2Value2,Col3Value2']
```

How do i convert this string to pyspark Dataframe like below

'\n' being a new row

```
Column1         Column2         Column3
-----------------------------------------
Col1Value1      Col2Value1      Col3Value1
Col1Value2      Col2Value2      Col3Value2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to convert the list of string in the correct format like this:

```
# convert the list of string into proper format
>>> l = ' '.join(ListofString)
>>> l = l.replace(',',' ')
>>> l = [x.strip().split(' ') for x in l.split('\n')]

>>> print(l)

>>> [['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'], ['Col1Value1', 'Col2Value1', 'Col3Value1'], ['Col1Value2', 'Col2Value2', 'Col3Value2']]

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l[1:],l[0])

>>> df.show()

+----------+----------+----------+
|   Column1|   Column2|   Column3|
+----------+----------+----------+
|Col1Value1|Col2Value1|Col3Value1|
|Col1Value2|Col2Value2|Col3Value2|
+----------+----------+----------+
```